# What distinctions between Exclusive vs Exceptive Propositions have I overlooked?

Tags: logic, propositions, arugmentation

Abbreviate 'Standard Form Categorical Propositions' to SFCP and 'Ordinary Statements' to OS.

<sub>Source: p 256-257, *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014) by Patrick Hurley.

The textbook did not generalise the translations (from OS into SFCP); please correct my attempts below if necessary.</sub>

> 8. Exclusive Propositions
>
> Many propositions that involve the words “only,” “none but,” “none
>   except,” and “no . . . except” are exclusive propositions.  [...] For
>   a statement involving “only,” “none but,” “none except,” and “no . . .
>   except” to be a genuinely exclusive proposition, the word that follows
>   these words must be a *plural* noun or pronoun.

[8.1.] Only S are P       => All P are S.
[8.2.] None but X are P     => All P are X.
[8.3.] No S except X are Y    => All S that are Y, are X.
[8.4.] S owned only X and Y.   => All Y that S owns are X and Y.

> 10. Exceptive Propositions
>
> Propositions of the form “All except S are P” and “All but S are P”
>   are exceptive propositions. They must be translated not as single
>   categorical propositions but as pairs of conjoined categorical
>   propositions. Statements that include the phrase “none except,” on the
>   other hand, are exclusive (not exceptive) propositions. “None except”
>   is synonymous with “none but.” Here are some examples of exceptive
>   propositions:

[10.1] All but/except X are Y.    => No X are Y, and all non-X are Y.

I see that, and so ask not about how, the SFCP for 8 differ from the SFCP for 10.
Instead, what are the subtler differences between 'exclusive' from 'exceptive' (synonyms in ordinary English)?

I am confused how the OS for 8 and 10 produce different SFCP. To me, the Function Morphemes in 8 and 10 both appear to exclude and except. For example, in 8, 'only' and 'none but/except' select a subset (from a set) about which the proposition then asserts something; but 'all but/except' in 10 does this too! So what subtleties did I overlook?

Answer (score 1):

From the logical perspective you take at the end, all these forms fall under the rubric like

> [All/Some/No] X but Y, are Z.

which becomes

> [All/Some/No] X that is not Y, is Z.

Then X can be omitted and filled in from the context.

If I say

> None but Y, are Z

I mean

> No X but Y, are Z

where X is everything, resulting in the interpretation you already reached

> All Z are Y

But if I say

> All but Y, are Z

And I take that as

> All X but Y, are Z

And I take X to be 'everything', so we get

> All of *everything* that is not Y is Z

The 'everything' does not cancel out in the math, as it does in the other cases.  But I cannot reduce that to the right form.  We cannot quantify over everything in a positive way by reference to a property.  Instead, we have to capture the main point in one statement,

> No Y is Z

And the reference to everything indirectly in another, in the form of 'everything else'

> All non-Y are Z.